# Receive Packet Acknowledgement from NDIS to Miniport Layer

Tags: windows-ce, ndis

When developing a PCIe - Ethernet driver in Wince 7 .

Send packet is working fine but on receive when we dump buffer at miniport layer we are receiving the packet but once sent to NDIS we don't get any flags or acknowledgement from NDIS to Miniport .

Is there any API or OID or function helping on this cause ?

Comment: what sort of acknowledgement from NDIS are you looking for, and are you using NDIS 5 or 6? Generally, the idea is that your miniport transfers bytes from the hardware and puts them in a buffer previously received from NDIS. The miniport then 'indicates' the packet by calling `NdisMIndicateReceivePacket` (NDIS5), passing ownership of the buffer to NDIS. NDIS passes new RX buffers to the miniport by calling `ReturnPacketHandler` (NDIS5) or `ReturnNetBufferListsHandler` (NDIS6)

Comment: I am using NDIS 6 ...The packet loss during RX has been rectified . Debugged using packet capture tool at NDIS level....Anyhow ty @CarstenHansen  for info regarding RX buffer ownership